# What does build number mean for the App Store?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, app-store

I uploaded a build of my app to the app store with version 4.1.10 and build number 1. I made a minor update and am wondering whether to upload it as 4.1.11 (1) or 4.1.10 (2). What difference does it make to users downloading the app?

Comment: Has 4.1.10 been approved and released?  If so then you must increment the version number. You can increment the build number within a version before it is released (eg for TestFlight or if a build is rejected during app review). Users don't really see or care about version or build numbers

Answer (score 0):

You change app store version to indicates that this is a new version for AppStore.
You change build number to indicates that is is a new version to test before publishing to AppStore.
So, while an App version is not in AppStore, just increase the build number.